# Cascading of Lookup input textbox Fields Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, cascading

I am trying to implement cascading input textbox for list in SharePoint online.

I have 2 lists with names Finance and Country.

I am trying to display Finance for selected country in SharePoint Online list.

Answer (score 1):

[here is solution for SPO on Technet.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39842.cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365.aspx)

*Hope it helps!*

Answer (score 1):

cascading input textbox?

Maybe your meaning is there is a dropdown list and an input textbox, is it right?

In SharePoint online, you can use REST API to do that.

References for you:
[Cascading drop down in SharePoint using REST API](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2017/06/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint.html)